# AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request in azure

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am working on azure rest API to Get Page Ranges using PHP. I am following the rest API documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Get-Page-Ranges)

I am unable to authenticate the rest API it says

> The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '6fsdfhyuiz78' is not the
>   same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign
>   GET

I am using the below code to get the page ranges. I have missed something here while passing the request headers to generate the string to sign authentication signature. It would be great if someone can help me out in this.

```
$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
$account_name = "account name";
$containername = "container name";
$blob = "blobname.vhd";

$mypremiumdisk_ss1 = "2017-09-12V09:15:43.00001Z";
$mypremiumdisk_ss2 = "2017-09-12V09:55:47.00002Z";

$account_key = "account key";

$canonicalizedHeaders  = "x-ms-date:$date\nx-ms-version:2015-07-08";
$canonicalizedResource = "/$account_name/$containername/$blob\ncomp:pagelist\nsnapshot:$mypremiumdisk_ss1\nprevsnapshot:$mypremiumdisk_ss2";

$arraysign = array();
$arraysign[] = 'GET';                     /*HTTP Verb*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Encoding*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Language*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-MD5*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Content-Type*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Date*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Modified-Since */  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-None-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                        /*Range*/  
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedHeaders;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
$arraysign[] = $canonicalizedResource;    /*CanonicalizedResource*/

$stringtosign = implode("\n", $arraysign);

$signature = 'SharedKey'.' '.$account_name.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringtosign, base64_decode($account_key), true));
$endpoint = 'https://'.$account_name.'.blob.core.windows.net';
echo $url = $endpoint.'/'.$containername.'/'.$blob.'?comp=pagelist&snapshot='.$mypremiumdisk_ss1.'&prevsnapshot='.$mypremiumdisk_ss2; 

$headers = [
    "x-ms-date:{$date}",
    'x-ms-version:2015-07-08',
    'Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata',
    'Accept-Charset:UTF-8',
    "Authorization:{$signature}"
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);        
echo '<pre>';print_r($response);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include 2 things: 1) `$stringtosign` output and 2) response body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

```
$mypremiumdisk_ss1 = "2017-09-12V09:15:43.00001Z";
$mypremiumdisk_ss2 = "2017-09-12V09:55:47.00002Z";
```

Please change `V` in the date/time values to `T`.

```
$canonicalizedResource = "/$account_name/$containername/$blob\ncomp:pagelist\nsnapshot:$mypremiumdisk_ss1\nprevsnapshot:$mypremiumdisk_ss2";
```

Based on the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services), `canonicalizedResource` should contain query parameters alphabetically sorted. Please change the above line to:

```
$canonicalizedResource = "/$account_name/$containername/$blob\ncomp:pagelist\nprevsnapshot:$mypremiumdisk_ss2\nsnapshot:$mypremiumdisk_ss1";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Its working now. Presnapshot and snapshot had no difference, fixed the issue by added some data on the disk and took the snapshot of the disk again.